# asp.net Web Reference build error

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf

Anyone knows what causes the following error?

`The type or namespace name 'ObservableCollection' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Collections.ObjectModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?) c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\myweb\ea5ddc82\99690bad\App_WebReferences.7f8qgamu.0.cs`

It turned out the there was a conflict with my IIS Virtual Directory.
So what I did was remove the application in my IIS.

Comment: This seem to be runtime error, right? Do you also get any warning during compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the correct assembly in your project that uses the ObservableCllection. In the case of ObservableCollection this dll was changed from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.

Prior to .NET 4, ObservableCollection was in WindowsBase.dll and since .Net 4 it is in System.dll. So I guess it depends on the framework version you compile against.

Comment: I already added the reference to System.dll but the error is still there.. I also noticed that when I open the App_WebReference temp files, the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection does not highlight as normal reserved words